# Java RestController REST parameter dependency injection or request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying inject a dependency or at least filtrate the ID parameter that come into a RestControler in Spring. I am very new in Spring. How can i be sure that the parameter that comes passed in the API is valid and/or how can i inject its dependency related to Customer Entity?

This is my rest controller CustomerController method

```
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public Customer updateCustomer(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return customerService.updateCustomer(id, customer);
    }
```

This is the request that at the moment filtrates only the firstname and last name

```
package com.appsdeveloperblock.app.ws.requests.customer;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class CreateCustomerRequest {


    @NotNull
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull
    private String lastname;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }


}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Bean Validation API (which you probably already have) and it's reference implementation (e.g. hibernate-validator). Check here [Java Bean Validation Basics](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

**Summarizing**

1. Add the respective dependencies to your pom.xml (or gradle):

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2. Use `@Valid` annotation on your `Customer` entity to have the payload validated automatically:

```java
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
public Customer updateCustomer(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Valid Customer customer) {
  return customerService.updateCustomer(id, customer);
}
```

3. You can decorate the fields of your `Customer` or `CreateCustomerRequest` class with further annotations, e.g. `@Size`, `@Max`, `@Email` etc. Check the tutorial for more information.

Comment: you don't have to manually add these dependencies as they come with the `spring-boot-starter-web`  which includes `spring-boot-starter-validation` by default